# MediaRouterProvider not visible in the network

Tags: android, casting, upnp, mediarouter

I created a `SampleMediaRouteProvider`  as given in https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MediaRouter. In this sample there is also a `MediaRouter` that discovers all `MediaRouteProviders` in the network. 
This `SampleMediaRouteProvider` is visible in the same device to other apps but its not visible to apps on other device in the same network.

Can you please help me to get `MediaRouteProvider` visible in wifi network. 
Iam looking to create a `MediaRenderer` on a Android device that I could use to cast audio from other Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

MediaRouteProvider doesn't really do what you're asking.

The MediaRouteProvider, which you've written, has the role of allowing apps on your phone - device A - to find other devices on the network (device B or C).  Device B and C can play the media you have on device A.  Device A might stream/mirror directly (say to device B) or 'cast' (say to device C).

When mirroring, you send the audio content out of device A to device B.  When casting, you only send a URL to device C, for example, the link to a video on youtube.com.  And device C goes directly to the source to get the content.

I think you will need to:

- Put your MediaRouteProvider on every device.
- Implement a discovery mechanism

  - for example, based on using SSDP, mDNS, etc.
  - have your mediarouter implmenent discovery
- Implement a webserver on the device(s) with content

  - or use something like nanohttpd
- Now Write your MediaRenderer